# How to set SSRS parameter Default to uncheck specific options?

Tags: ssrs

In a multi-select Parameter for SSRS (2008), I want the default state of an input parameter to be such that one option is unchecked while all others are checked. Like in the image that follows:

[image]

Is there any way in SSRS that this can be accomplished? I guess there is no way to refer to a "checked" state so this can be handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the parameter preference pane, there's one tab for available, and one tab for default. You can pick completely different details for each set, including different datasets, one with the available options, and one selecting just the ones you want set as defaults.

Comment: Wouldn't manual addition in defaults be like hardcoding? I want it to populate from a query but leave one unchecked so we don't have to change or add to defaults manually.

Comment: Then you use two data sets. One that pulls back all the possible values, and one that pulls the same ones back minus the one you don't want selected.

Comment: How can we point it to two datasets? I thought Default or Available values could only be associated with one dataset.

Comment: In the parameter preference pane, there's one tab for available, and one tab for default. You can pick completely different details for each set, including data set.

Comment: Ah yes! Yes you're right, I did it just now, NOW I know what you mean. Can you post this as answer so I can choose it as such. Thank you very much for this.

Comment: I've edited it to just that.